# Proving that Hermitian Metric yields Hermitian Structure on Complex Manifold

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, riemannian-geometry, complex-geometry

Let $g$ be a Riemannian metric on an almost complex manifold $(M,J)$. Suppose $g$ is Hermitian in the sense that

$$g(JX,JY) = g(X,Y)$$

Let $\Omega$ be the associated fundamental (Kahler) form

$$\Omega(X,Y) = g(JX,Y)$$

We may extend $g$ and $\Omega$ complex linearly to be defined on $TM^{\mathbb{C}}$.

I've seen it written that the following defines a Hermitian structure on $M$

$$h(X,Y) = g(X,Y) - i\Omega(X,Y)$$

My question is why?! I'm assuming this is defined on $TM^\mathbb{C}$: am I correct? How does it relate to the "standard" Hermitian structure on the holomorphic bundle $TM^+$ given by

$$h^+(X,Y) = g(X,\overline{Y})\textrm{?}$$

**Attempted argument**

We want to show $\overline{h(X,Y)}=h(Y,X)$. It's easy to prove $\overline{g(X,Y)}=g(\overline{X},\overline{Y})$. We write

$$\overline{h(X,Y)} = g(\overline{X},\overline{Y}) + ig(\overline{JX},\overline{Y})$$

We'll try cases. If $X$ and $Y$ are both in $TM^+$ or $TM^-$ one can easily show

$$g(X,Y) = g(\overline{X},\overline{Y})=0$$

*Note : therefore this is very different from the "standard" Hermitian structure.*

By symmetry we only need try $X\in TM^+, Y\in TM^-$. Then

$$\overline{h(X,Y)} = 2g(\overline{X},\overline{Y})$$

$$h(Y,X) = 2g(X,Y)$$

But these aren't equal necessarily! What on earth am I doing wrong here? It should be dead simple, but I'm just going round in circles. If someone could point out the silly mistake I'm making I'd be very grateful!

Comment: I think that part of the confusion follows from calling $g$ hermitian: it is in no sense hermitian, since it only takes real values. Just say that it is riemannian **and**  $J$-invariant.

Comment: But one can consider $g$ to take complex values, by extending by complex linearity. I know that $g$ itself is not really Hermitian, but the nomenclature "Hermitian metric" for $g$ seems to be prevelant. The Hermitian structure is the thing that is genuinely Hermitian, of course.

Comment: Dear Edward, you can extend $g$ to the complexified tangent bundle $T(M)^\mathbb C$ in several ways but you should then call these extensions $g^\mathbb C$. My point is that there is no need to do this in a first step, and my answer gives the situation obtained without complexification. If you are confused, it is a bad idea to abuse notation and denote  several  functions of two arguments with different domains  by the same letter $g$.

Comment: Ah okay. I see now that your Hermitian structure on $TM$ as a $\mathbb{C}$-bundle is exactly my holomorphic one $h^+$ under the canonical isomorphism $X \leftrightarrow X-iJX$. But I still don't understand why I can't demonstrate the Hermiticity if I extend $g$, $\Omega$ and $h$ to the complexified tangent space in the same linear manner. Okay I could put subscript $\mathbb{C}$s everywhere, but I've tried that on paper and I still reach the impasse above. There must be a way through!

Comment: The problem is: how do you extend $g,h,\omega$ ? One possibility would be to take bilinear $\mathbb C$-extension where now the complex structure comes from the factor $\mathbb C$ in $T(M)^\mathbb C=T(M)\otimes _\mathbb R \mathbb C$ and **not** by using $J$.

Comment: Yes - that was the possibility I was thinking of. So on $T(M)$ thought of as a $\mathbb{C}$-bundle we know that $h(X,Y) = g(X,Y) - i\omega(X,Y)$ and moreover $h$ is Hermitian. So we extend all three of these forms to $T(M)^\mathbb{C} = T(M)\otimes_{\mathbb{R}}\mathbb{C}$. Then $h$ is still Hermitian, and the above relation still holds due to linearity. But this contradicts my findings in the question. Where is my error of logic? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Or thinking about it - maybe $h$ isn't Hermitian, since anti-linearity in the second argument doesn't get preserved. Am I on the right track?

Comment: Yes, I think you should extend everything $\mathbb C$- bilinearly and then $h^\mathbb C$ will only be hermitian on the eigenspace $T'(M)\subset T(M)^\mathbb C$ of $J^\mathbb C$ with eigenvalue $i$. Can you check that ?

Comment: I think it's even simpler than that. In order for the relation between $h,g,\omega$ to carry over to the complexification we must extend them all in the same way, i.e. complex bilinearly. But this means that $h$ will now only be Hermitian on the real subspace. That is $h$ will only be Hermitian when $X = \overline{X}$ and $Y = \overline{Y}$ agreeing with my observation in the question. In particular $h^{\mathbb{C}}$ so constructed doesn't yield the form $h^+$ on $T^+(M)$. The form $h^+$ is a different form, obtained via the canonical isomorphism of $T^+(M)$ with $T(M)$.

Comment: So to conclude - it is fairly meaningless to extend a Hermitian structure on $T(M)$ to $T(M)^{\mathbb{C}}$. Instead one usually extends the Hermitian metric $g$ to $g^{\mathbb{C}}$ complex bilinearly whence it's matrix of components becomes Hermitian (as also seen in the question). Unfortunately people use different conventions for all of the nomenclature - hence why I got confused.

Comment: Dear Edward, you are absolutely right, and on the other hand my suggestion  above was incorrect. I am impressed by the depth of your understanding of these very confusing matters: bravo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assume $(M,J)$ is an almost complex manifold of real dimension $2n$: for example a complex manifold of complex dimension $n$.
Given a $J$-invariant  **riemannian**   structure $g$ on $(M,J)$, you derive from it:
a) A $J$-invariant **hermitian** structure $h$  defined by $h(X,Y)=g(X,Y)-ig(JX,Y)$ on  $T(M)$.
Here T(M) is seen, by using $J$, as a complex vector bundle of complex rank $n$.
Hermitianity means  that    you have, among other conditions, $h(X,JY)=-ih(X,Y)$ .
b) An alternating $\mathbb C$-bilinear $2$-form $\omega (X,Y)\stackrel {def}{=}g(JX,Y)$ on $T(M)$
Here $\mathbb C$-bilinear means that you have, among other conditions, $\omega(X,JY)=i\omega(X,Y)$

These structures are related by the obvious equation $h(X,Y)=g(X,Y)-i\omega (X,Y)$ .
Everything happens on $T(M)$ provided with its complex $J$-structure and there is no need to complexify the vector bundle $T(M)$.

Comment: Thanks very much for your answer! But what happens when you do complexify the bundle? In his Complex Geometry text, Huybrechts suggests that you can and $h$ gives you a Hermitian structure on the complexification also. In which case why does my "proof" in the question fail? I'll happily award the bounty if you can demonstrate my erroneous reasoning. Thanks very much once again!

Comment: It is not clear to me that Huybrechts complexifies the tangent bundle: where does he do that? In  his Definition 3.1.1 he uses the real tangent bundle with its complex structure $I$, just as in my answer. Also, beware that textbook authors are often quite inaccurate in these matters.

Comment: Hmm yes you are right - I misread Huybrechts.

Comment: Further to my comments above on the question I think we're probably agreed that this is solved! Apparently I have to wait 24 hours until awarding you the bounty. I shall return tomorrow and do so.

Comment: Yes, I agree: your last comments under your question are very pertinent and solve the problem.

Comment: It seems to me, tat the condition b) with the equation $h(X,Y)=g(X,Y)-i\omega(X,Y)$ imply $h(X,Y)=0$. Because, $i\omega(X,Y)=\omega(X,JY)=g(JX,JY)=g(X,Y)$. Is this correct then?